# python 3.8.6 sox example will not work, the conversions are not working, the out wave files are unplayable

Tags: python-3.x, sox

has anyone made this following python sox example work:

the data conversations do not take place,

The output files are unplayable and look to contain 32 bit data

I think pysox may be passing the wrong format to sox or pysox and sox do not match. using python 3.8.6 in win 7 64 bit

no errors are shown, print statements show the data as we go

````
    import numpy as np
    import sox
    
        # sample rate in Hz
    sample_rate = 44100
    
        # generate a 1-second sine tone at 440 Hz
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 440.0 * np.arange(sample_rate * 1.0) / sample_rate)
       
    
    #this print just prints first and last
    print(y)
    
          # create a transformer
    tfm = sox.Transformer()
    
        # shift the pitch up by 2 semitones
    tfm.pitch(2)
    
        # transform an in-memory array and return an array
    y_out = tfm.build_array(input_array=y, sample_rate_in=sample_rate)
    
    print(y,y_out)
    
        # instead, save output to a file
    tfm.build_file(
            input_array=y, sample_rate_in=sample_rate,
            output_filepath='./output/output.wav'
            
        )
        # create an output file with a different sample rate
    tfm.set_output_format(rate=8000)
    tfm.build_file(
            input_array=y, sample_rate_in=sample_rate,
            output_filepath='./output/output_8k.wav'
        )
    ```
````

Comment: Did you miss that `set_output_format` has a `bits` parameter?

Comment: Thanks, just learned to forget the -- and just use the words it now works : # transform output to a legit .wav file with headers
tfm.set_output_format(bits=16), really appreciate the heads-up it is all playable now i know how to word the arguments. just post answer and get the points

Comment: I don't really need the points, but I'll post an answer just because that's the way the system works best.  I didn't do it earlier because I don't have sox installed so I had no way to test it, but I'll take your word that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_output_format` has [quite a few parameters](https://pysox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#sox.transform.Transformer.set_output_format) that can be set, beyond just `rate`.  One of them is `bits` which appears to be exactly what you're looking for.

```
tfm.set_output_format(bits=16)
```

You could probably set it at the same time you're setting the rate:

```
tfm.set_output_format(rate=8000, bits=16)
```

Comment: On target precisely, most players spit out  32bit .wav seems it default to big endian.